# Continuous functions. And their max and min

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given continuous functionals f and g on a topological space. Then are the functionals $\min_{f,g}(x) := \min(f(x),g(x))$ and $\max_{f,g}(x) := \max(f(x),g(x))$ continuous functionals?

If $f \leq g$ on some interval for each x, then $\min(x) - \max(x) = (f-g)(x)$ and there are continuous at every point, so are $\min - \max$ is continuous. Likewise $\min+ \max$ is continuous too.

Hence $2\min$ and $2\max$ are continuous. So $\min$ and $\max$ are too.

The thing is, I am assuming that for each $x$, there exists some interval around x which $f \leq g$ or $g\leq f$ which is in general not true. So I need to fill in that possibility.

Anyway, this way may be a 'red herring'. But I'd be interested to see a 'fix', or a slick new argument.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by continuous functional on a topological space $X$? Is it a continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If so, it is preferable to call this a continuous real valued function. A functional is usually a linear object.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need this considertions. The function
$$
\max:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}
$$
is continuous. The maps $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous. So their composition 
$$
\max(f(-),g(-)):X\times X\mapsto\mathbb{R}
$$ 
is also continuous. The same argument works for $\min$.