# Problems about continuity of $|f|$ and $f\vee g$; confusion about definitions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I can't seem to wrap my head around this notation of my textbook can some please explain to me what this says? What I am trying to show?

> (a) Given  $f: D \to \mathbb {R}$, let $|f|$  be the function defined by
>   $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$ for $x\in D$. Show that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then so is $|f|$. Is the converse true?

Attempting to prove that if f(x) is cont then |f(x)| is cont.

Lets define h(y) =|y| the absolute value function is continuous for all $y \in \mathbb {R}$ f(x) is continuous on D. thus $|f| = h(y) \circ f(x)$ hence |f| is a composition of continuous function's thus continuous by theorem.

$|f|$ is continuous just because $f(x)$ was, but the converse is an easy argument: assume $[a,b] \subset D$ and that $0 \in D$ let $f(x)= a$ for all $x \geq \frac {a+b}{2}$ let $f(x)=b$ for all $x<0$, $|f|=a$ for all $x \in D$ $f(x)$ is discontinuous at 0 as the LHS $\neq$ RHS since it isnt true for all D that any f(x) is continuous on its not true in general.

> (b) Given two functions $f$ and $g$  define a function $f\vee g$ by $(f\vee g) (x) = \max\{f(x), g(x)\}$. Show that
>   if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x_0$ then $f\vee g$ is continuous at $x_0$. (Hint: you can do this either directly using the definition of continuity or by showing first that 
>   $\max\{\alpha, \beta\} = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha +\beta + |\alpha - \beta|)$ for  $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and then using part (a))

once i finally understood this i wrongly assumed it was false unless g(x)>f(x) or vice versa but as long as there both continuous they can switch many times  as the point where they switch g(x) = f(x) then this weird thing will take the bigger one so its always continuous.

This one still has me a bit lost lets define all $x_{0} \in S$ ( i can't tell from the question but there may only be one thing in S) let a be in S then we know that  $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are continuous  the composition of 2 continuous functions is continuous so $\text {max}(f(x_{0}),G(x_{0}))$ such that $S \times S \to \mathbb {R}$ is also continous.

Comment: The definitions of $|f|$ and $f \vee g$ are literally right here in your post.

Comment: What do you mean it "does not define it"? The definitions are right there in the problem statement:
$$|f|(x)=|f(x)|,\qquad (f\vee g)(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$$
for each $x\in D$.

Comment: so absolotue value of f? and the sup of f,g as a ordered pair?

Comment: i dont understand what that says

Comment: @Faust7: Do you understand that one can define a function $h:D\to \mathbb{R}$ by specifying, for each $x\in D$, the value of $h(x)$?

Comment: you have to do that with each element $x_{1} \in D$ or youd have a constant function or recursivly define it etc. im sure if you coudl translate it to words i would understand it ?

Comment: i can change the question  if you like to what does $|f(x)|$ and $max \{ f(x),g(x)\}$ mean?

Comment: @Faust7: That's exactly what I said: "*specifying, for each $x\in D$, the value of $h(x)$*". Writing $x_1$ vs. $x$ makes no difference. Anyway, if we have been given a function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$, then for each $x\in D$, there is a corresponding real number $f(x)$ (do you understand this?) As with any real number, I can take the absolute value of $f(x)$, which is denoted $|f(x)|$ (do you understand this?) I can now define my new function $h:D\to \mathbb{R}$ by setting, for each $x\in D$, the value of $h(x)$ to be
$$h(x)\overset{\text{def}}{=}|f(x)|$$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8784/discussion-between-faust7-and-zev-chonoles)

Comment: @Faust7: What you've added is correct general idea, but it is not a complete proof. What if it **weren't** true that $[-1,1]\subset D$ - how would you generalize your argument to work for any set $D$? And **why** isn't $f$ continuous at $0$ - can you *prove* that it isn't?

Comment: i definatly can't prove that its not continous but any set D thats non empty in the reals contains an interval ( since f is continous ) or just 1 point  let $[a,b] \subset D$ then $\frac {a+b}{2} \in D$ make the argument for a or b instead of 1 i guess i could make an argument that lim $x \to 0^{+}$ does not equal $lim x\to 0^{-}$ but if you want me to slap down some e and d's those are more confusing then the notation of this question.

Comment: Similar question in a more general setting: [Continuous functions. And their max and min](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/continuous-functions-and-their-max-and-min).
The argument is basically that your function is composition of two continuous functions $x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ (going from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$) and $(x,y)\mapsto\max\{x,y\}$ (going from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$). Similar argument is easier for absolute value, you compose $x\mapsto f(x)$ and $x\mapsto|x|$, both of them are real functions. (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) You also need to know that composition of two continuous function is again continuous. However, for a beginner the more general approach might be less useful, it is better to work the details for some particular case before going to generalities.